# Map list of filenames as option values for command

Tags: bash, shell, dictionary, command-line-arguments

I have a number of files and want to use their names as arguments to a command so that the command becomes

```
<command> <option> <file1> <option> <file2> ...
```

For each file name I want to prepend that with the option name. I don't know how many files there are. How can I do this? Does bash/shell have something similar to `map`?

The files exists so I would get the names using `find`, or mayb `ls` if I'm sure about the filenames, so I was looking for something like you can do with `xargs`

```
ls -1q <pattern> | xargs <command> ...
```

But instead of what `xargs` do (turning it into one command for each file) I want a single command with many arguments with `<option>` inserted before all filenames.

In my specific example I want to combine an unknown number of coverage data files with one command:

```
lcov -o total.coverage -a <file1> -a <file2> ...
```

This is inside a Makefile, but I'd prefer a "standard" shell approach.

Comment: Where does the lists is coming from?

Comment: `I have list of filenames` how are the filenames stored? Inside a bash array? In a file? In a variable? In a make variable? In bash variable?  Are entries in the variable separated by newlines? Are they zero terminated? By some other character? Please post some code. `Does bash/shell have something similar to map?` yes, bash has associative ararys..

Comment: They're not coming from anywhere. Edited to be more clear about that.

Comment: `The files exists so I would get the names using ls` [do  not parse ls output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: @KamilCuk agreed in general, but in this case I'm in complete control over the files and their names. But I'll update for the benefit of the more general case.

Comment: Then _at least_ use `ls -1`. (`ls -1q`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
files=(pattern)
# This will expand the [pattern], and put all the files in [files] variables

lcov -o total.coverage ${files[@]/#/-a }
# ${files[@]/#/-a } replaces the beginning of each element in files with [-a ],
# meaning prepend [-a ]
# For more information, see section [${parameter/pattern/string}] in
# https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion
```

assuming you don't have special characters (like spaces) in your file names.

Comment: Perfect! If you explain a little more, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Oops. Of course, didn't work in a Makefile (`bash` instead of `sh` which is the standard shell used by `make`). But since I wanted a general solution it's still a candidate ;-)

Comment: I think you can redefine SHELL in your Makefile.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
ls <pattern> |sed "s/^/-optionItself /g"|xargs
```

thus appending `-optionItself` in front of each filename, and then sending it to `xargs`

I am sure there are many other ways for this to be accomplished, this is the simplest and closest to what you work with.

Comment: This is also nice. And it's standard shell, which works in a Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

While finding the files also print the option, use zero separated streams to handle all possible filenames:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf "-a\0%p\0" | xargs -0 lcov -o total.coverage
```

The same with a newline as a separator for list elements:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf "-a\n%p\n" | xargs -d '\n' lcov -o total.coverage
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
function multi_lcov(){
  files_params=($@)
  lcov ${files_params[@]}
}

multi_lcov "$(ls | sed -r 's/(.*)/\-a \1/g')"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fileslist=( $(cd /path/to/files/you/want/ ;find -maxdepth 1 -printf "%P\n" | xargs -0) )
for t in ${fileslist[@]} 
do
commandtoperform $t
done
```

Comment: `-printf "%P\n" | xargs -0` makes no sense. Just `printf "%P\n"`.